# Body Load HTML with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, timeout

Hi this is my hmtl and JS so far what i would like is for it to detect mousemove, scroll and arrows in the iframe windows as well, as most of the website is in iframe i have looked else where and all seems overly complicated to detect movement.

Any help will be appreciated 
thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Set timeout variables.
        var timoutWarning = 1000; // Display warning in 1Mins.
        var timoutNow = 2000; // Timeout in 2 mins.

        var warningTimer;
        var timeoutTimer;

        // Start timers.
        function StartTimers() {
            warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
            timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
        }

        // Reset timers.
        function ResetTimers() {
            clearTimeout(warningTimer);
            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            StartTimers();
            $("#timeout").dialog('close');
        }

        // Show idle timeout warning dialog.
        function IdleWarning() {
            var answer = confirm("Session About To Timeout\n\n       You will be automatically logged out.\n       Confirm to remain logged in.")
                if (answer){

                    ResetTimers();
                }
                else{
                    IdleTimeout();
                }
        }       

        // Logout the user and auto reload or use this window.open('http://www.YourPageAdress.com', '_self'); to auto load a page.
        function IdleTimeout() {
            window.open(self.location,'_top');
        }
    </script>

    <body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();" onKeyPress="ResetTimers();"
```

Comment: Each frame has it's own window and events occur inside that window and don't bubble to the parent of the frame. So you would need to be able to listen for movement inside those frames also and coordinate with top page

Answer (score 0):

some thing like *

```js
$(".in").on("mouseover",function(){
   $(this).css("background","blue");
});
$(".in").on("mouseout",function(){
   $(this).css("background","green");
});
```

```css
.in{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="in"></div>
```

- and use multiple like this `$("selector").on("mouseover mouseout mousemove",function(){
  call back
  });`